# How to use Express's RequestHandler AND inversify-express-utils's BaseMiddleware on a single controller

Tags: node.js, express, inversion-of-control, middleware, inversifyjs

There are two middleware functions I'm trying to use - one is the express request handler interface (third party package - bull monitor) and the other is inversify-express-utils's BaseMiddleware (auth and admin auth middlwares). I tried to implement the basemiddleware and just call the express middleware's router function as told to do [here](https://github.com/s-r-x/bull-monitor/tree/main/packages/express#usage). but the response is 404.

Middleware:
[image: middleware]

Controller:
[image: controller]

I also tried registering the middleware after inversify express server is built, and injecting handler methods as middleware, but the handler signature is async and doesn't conform to the express handler interface.

[image: Register 'BaseMiddleware' handlers]

How are you supposed to mix these middlewares?

Thanks!